# WordPress job and resume board not working

Tags: php, wordpress, code-snippets

i just developed a job and resume upload code for my website hoping it will work. Am using code snippets plugin to add the code.
after adding the code, i get menu shortcut on my dashboard menu: illustrated in the pic.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pc05G.png)

how do i develop short code to add to a page.

attached is the developed code:

```
// This file contains the code needed to create a job and resume plugin for your WordPress site.
// First, we need to create a function that will register the custom post type for our job and resume posts.
function register_job_resume_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => 'Jobs & Resumes',
        'singular_name'      => 'Job & Resume',
        'add_new'            => 'Add New',
        'add_new_item'       => 'Add New Job & Resume',
        'edit_item'          => 'Edit Job & Resume',
        'new_item'           => 'New Job & Resume',
        'all_items'          => 'All Jobs & Resumes',
        'view_item'          => 'View Job & Resume',
        'search_items'       => 'Search Jobs & Resumes',
        'not_found'          => 'No jobs & resumes found',
        'not_found_in_trash' => 'No jobs & resumes found in Trash',
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Jobs & Resumes'
    );
   $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'job-resume' ),
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'job-resume', $args );
}
// We also need to create a function to register the custom taxonomies for our job and resume posts.
function register_job_resume_taxonomies() {
    // Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical (like categories)
    $labels = array(
        'name'              => 'Job & Resume Categories',
        'singular_name'     => 'Job & Resume Category',
        'search_items'      => 'Search Job & Resume Categories',
        'all_items'         => 'All Job & Resume Categories',
        'parent_item'       => 'Parent Job & Resume Category',
        'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Job & Resume Category:',
        'edit_item'         => 'Edit Job & Resume Category',
        'update_item'       => 'Update Job & Resume Category',
        'add_new_item'      => 'Add New Job & Resume Category',
        'new_item_name'     => 'New Job & Resume Category Name',
        'menu_name'         => 'Job & Resume Categories'
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'labels'            => $labels,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => array( 'slug' => 'job-resume-category' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'job-resume-category', array( 'job-resume' ), $args );

    // Add new taxonomy, NOT hierarchical (like tags)
    $labels = array(
        'name'                       => 'Job & Resume Tags',
        'singular_name'              => 'Job & Resume Tag',
        'search_items'               => 'Search Job & Resume Tags',
        'popular_items'              => 'Popular Job & Resume Tags',
        'all_items'                  => 'All Job & Resume Tags',
        'parent_item'                => null,
        'parent_item_colon'          => null,
        'edit_item'                  => 'Edit Job & Resume Tag',
        'update_item'                => 'Update Job & Resume Tag',
        'add_new_item'               => 'Add New Job & Resume Tag',
        'new_item_name'              => 'New Job & Resume Tag Name',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separate job & resume tags with commas',
        'add_or_remove_items'        => 'Add or remove job & resume tags',
        'choose_from_most_used'      => 'Choose from the most used job & resume tags',
        'menu_name'                  => 'Job & Resume Tags'
    );

    $args = array(
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_admin_column'     => true,
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var'             => true,
        'rewrite'               => array( 'slug' => 'job-resume-tag' ),
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'job-resume-tag', 'job-resume', $args );
}

// Finally, we need to register our custom post type and taxonomies with WordPress.
 add_action( 'init', 'register_job_resume_post_type' );
 add_action( 'init', 'register_job_resume_taxonomies', 0 );
```

Assist me on how to sort it out.

step on how to make it work and develope shortcode for easy installation

Answer (score 0):

You would use the `add_shortcode()` function. This function takes two parameters: the name of the shortcode and then the callback function to display the shortcode content. See the code below.

```
function namespace_cpt_shortcode() {
    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'job-resume'
    ];

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
            $the_query->the_post();
            
            // Save the data you wish to show in the post
            $postTitle = get_the_title();
            $postContent = get_the_content();
            
            //Save the data to the variable that will be returned in the shortcode.
            $result = "
            <div class='post-container'>
            <h2>$postTitle</h2>
            <p>$postContent</p>
            </div>";

        } // End while loop
    } else {
        $result = "No posts found.";
    }
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
    
    return $result;
}
// Use add_shortcode() to create the shortcode. First parameter is the name of the shortcode and the second is the function name.
add_shortcode( 'job-listing', 'namespace_cpt_shortcode' );
```

If you want to add more post information to the layout, you would add it into the `$result` variable as that is what is being returned in the function because shortcodes require a returned value.